# Automapper: mapping collection and passing parameter

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map one entity to another (which has one additional field).

```
Group {
    int Id;
}

GroupExtended {
   int Id;
   string Description;
}
```

So I do the mapping in loop:

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
     var result = mapper.Map<Group, GroupExtended>(group,
                        opt => opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Description = someValue));
}
```

Is that possible to map entire IEnumerable, and still passing an the value ?
I tried this:

```
var result = mapper.Map<List<GroupExtended>>(groups,
                        opt => opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Description = someValue));
```

But it has an error on `dest.Description` : 'object' does not contain definition of "Description"

Comment: You shouldn't use AfterMap, you should use a custom value resolver for that property. And you can pass parameters to that resolver.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu can you show how you do it using custom resolver?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to map an entire collection and still pass the value.  Using a [custom value resolver](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) is probably the preferred option, as pointed out in the comment on your original post.  If you'd still prefer to use `AfterMap`, you can do something like the following, remembering that your source and destination in this case are collections rather than individual items:

```
var result = mapper.Map<List<Group>, List<GroupExtended>>(groups,
    opt => opt.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
    {
        foreach (var i in dest)
        {
            i.Description = "someValue";
        }
    }));
```